# How to find the query that I am trying to run in logs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying the do the following through Scala code:

```
val df=sqlContext.sql("select * from tab1")
df.write.option("header",false).csv("/tmp/loc/src")
```

But when I search for indication that query runs in logs, I'm not able to find any reference. How can I make sure that query is running by reading the logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `.queryName("my-sql-query")` which is going to help you identify that query is running in the logs, you can grep on it. Besides logs, you can refer to spark UI to check if your job is running properly, exact URL is available in logs after you start the application like so

```
2021-09-07 08:48:19,023 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.util.Utils  - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
```

There is also fixed spark UI of the master node if you have cluster setup.